# Toggle paper-drawer-panel inside paper-header-panel

Tags: polymer, paper-elements

I'm trying to use paper elements, and I played a bit with the different panels. I tried modifying the example from the documentation:

```
<paper-drawer-panel>
  <paper-header-panel drawer>
    <paper-toolbar><div>Application</div></paper-toolbar>
    <div> Drawer content... </div>
  </paper-header-panel>
  <paper-header-panel main>
    <paper-toolbar>
      <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
      <div>Title</div>
    </paper-toolbar>
    <div> Main content... </div>
  </paper-header-panel>
</paper-drawer-panel>
```

I want to have the drawer inside the header panel, so that the header take the whole width of the page.

Here is my attempt: ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/q298KO?p=preview))

```
  <body class="fullbleed layout vertical">
    <paper-header-panel>
      <paper-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" (click)="document.querySelector('#panel').togglePanel()"></paper-icon-button>
        <div>My app</div>
      </paper-toolbar>
      <paper-drawer-panel id="panel">
        <div drawer> drawer </div>
        <div main> main </div>
      </paper-drawer-panel>
    </paper-header-panel>
  </body>
```

Here, the drawer doesn't close. The buttons don't do anything. In my console, I can use `$('#panel').togglePanel()`, and I see it changing the `selected` attribute on the panel, but the drawer doesn't close. What's wrong with my code and how can I make the "menu" button close my drawer?

Edit: replaced `$('#panel')` by `document.querySelector('#panel')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were trying to use JQuery, here is the Javascript way of doing it:

replace:

```
(click)="$('#panel').togglePanel()"
```

with:

```
onClick="document.querySelector('#panel').togglePanel()"
```

Comment: It doesn't work any better. I updated the plunker with your suggestion. $() worked in the console for me, imported from polymer or angular2, not sure

Comment: Works for me http://plnkr.co/edit/SRChYXQMatrsGddudofs?p=preview
Just checking you are making it narrow enough to hide the draw (and you're pressing the second button)

Comment: Oh interesting. I'm on Chrome  48 and it doesn't work

Comment: I'm on 46, maybe it's a canary thing

Comment: Ah that's it, I wasn't making it narrow enough! Doh! Thanks a lot!